# How to make v4l2ucp's "Exposure, Auto Priority" persistent on reboot?

Tags: video, webcam, reboot

My laptop's webcam has the common too dark issue, and what fixes it is using v4l2ucp and activating "Exposure, Auto Priority". The problem is, the setting reverts after every reboot. Any way to make it persistent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out myself, posting here in case someone stumbles upon this with the same problem.

I figured v4l2ucp must be just a GUI for something that works with command line, so if I can find the command for auto exposure, I can run it on startup.

I found and installed the command line utility `v4l2-ctl` with:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

Reading its help with:

```
v4l2-ctl -h
```

I found it has a value called `exposure_auto_priority` which is used like:

```
v4l2-ctl -c exposure_auto_priority=1
```

Add that to your startup applications and you're cooking.

Comment: According to [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Webcam_setup#Persisting_configuration_changes), you can also do this with a udev rule, which should work for external webcams that you don't always have plugged in (as it'll be run automatically when they're connected).